# How can I host web pages with an ASP.NET Core web application - API project in Visual Studio?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio

I needed a REST server in Visual Studio so I choose the template ASP.NET Core web application and then I chose the "API" option, but I want to host web pages too.

That is a thing that I cannot figure out, do I need to make another ASP.NET Core project but choosing "Web application" or how can I host web pages from my initial project?

I tried to create a folder inside the project with a html page and then I tried to access it, but the server could not find the resource.

So the question is again, how do I host local web pages inside that project template?

Comment: Have you tried simply creating a new project, examining what it adds to the project in order to serve static files, then tried adding that to your original project?

Comment: I was goind to tried that but then i thought that there should be a better way of doing it. But if there is not other option i am going to to tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up dividing the project in two (and using java instead of C# and visual basic), one part is the web project (host the web pages) and the other one is the one with the Web Service, this was the best option for me in this moment.